# Updating Solr Index

Tags: solr, indexing

I created solr index on my machine using

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Now i have to update index on each add / edit/ delete on the table that i used for indexing.

Please advice the best way of updating solr index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr provides incremental-updates named delta-updates via the DataImportHandler:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command

But this might not be the fastest way if your index has many small and frequent changes which need to be available fast.

Comment: In my table there are around 1,50,000 rows and they will be increased. If i use DataImportHandler, then will it update the index automatically or i need to hit the url http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import again ?

Comment: I executed http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import but now it did not index my table as result was                    <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str> any advice?

Comment: Did you specify the deltaQuery ?

Comment: I forgot to add deltaQuery but after adding the query as same explained at link provided by you, has given result like <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str> However when i use solrclient to find a word then it works fine except one issue that data in not coming in alphabetical order that i provided in my query of data-config.xml

Comment: I added one new record in the table but its not coming up in the result. Am i missing anything ? Below is my entity           <entity name="users" 
  query="select * from users order by first_name"
  deltaImportQuery="select * from users where ID='${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
  deltaQuery="select id from users where modification_date &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">   
</entity>    DO I NEED TO HIT THE URL AGAIN http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import ?

Comment: Oh! i thought there should be automatic update on index otherwise i will have to run cron to make the update.

Comment: There is a scheduler configuration if you do want to do it this way see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#dataimport.properties_example

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Many Thanks to guide this. However just one small issue is that my result is not coming up in alphabetical order as i written query as query="select * from users order by first_name" in the <entity> tag. Is there a way i can pass the condition to fetch the result?

Comment: You may sort search results in solr http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

Comment: I set the configuration as described at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#dataimport.properties_example and set interval = 1 after that i inserted a record in the database but even after couple of minutes when i searched the same string, Number of records found were same as previous. Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: My query is $query = array('first_name:dd'); that i am using to seach the word "dd" in the document. How can we pass sort parameter in this query... Sorry i could not understand from the example given at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

Comment: Mh which sort of framework do you use ? Practically you need only to add a sort url parameter.

Comment: NO i am using SolrPHPClient and my code is <?php
require_once( 'SolrPHPClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php' );
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8983', '/solr/' );  
$offset = 0;
$limit = 10;  
$queries = array(
'first_name:dd'
);  
$response = $solr->search( $queries, $offset, $limit );    
.....

Comment: the accepted answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381978/why-wont-this-sort-in-solr-work will guide you ;)